# Ruchi Soya industries ltd shares

Tags: stock-markets, shares, selling, bankruptcy, nse-india

What is wrong with Ruchi Soya industries ltd shares (5% up per day). They are increasing in steps per day. There are 0 sellers, how can someone then buy those shares? Is only price increasing due to huge buy demand and buyers are not getting shares? Please clear my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

There are headlines to this effect:

**Patanjali Ayurved completes acquisition of bankrupt Ruchi Soya for Rs 4,350 crore**.

Is that your company?  If so, google for details.